# How do I use wget for the targets that are linked behind php or cgi etc scripts?

Tags: wget

Often times, I need to use wget from a remote non-gui login but I see that the links presented on webpages do not directly point to the file but rather a script that leads to the download. This means it is impossible to use wget to fetch the file. Instead, I have to do a browser download followed by scp to the remote login.

Is there a way, I can use wget to really target the intended file somehow!?

Comment: Can you add more information on what is exactly the problem you are facing? What do you mean by "rather a script that leads to the download"? You are given a Location: HTTP header or that you have to do a request to a script to get the file?

Comment: Well, think of some source tarball you need to download from sourceforge to a remote server, you have a commandline ssh access to. You would use wget <url_of_source_tarball>. However, the problem here is that sourceforge tarball links are not the ones that will lead to the tarball, they are rather the redirection links that will lead to a tarball. So, the need here is to have a trick to make sure wget actually gets the final link instead of the php that sourceforge gives you. Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: Ok, there is no general solution to your answer, and also no shell oneliner to get the file, but there is a general approach that involves analysing the http response/requests and the returned html data. Then you'll have to programmatically reproduce those steps with wget. I just answerd to a similar question, try to see if there is anything there to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809653/wget-not-working-properly/9809896#9809896